# How to share a video on Android form the rest api

Tags: android, android-studio, android-video-player, android-sharing, android-video-record

Im trying to share a clip which i fetch from the server. I am able to play the video on Video Player. Now I want to share that clip.

We have multiple clips and I need to share which ever clip user selects. We make the calls to fetch the video at the time of Thumbnail selection(We dont fetch all the videos until user selects the thumbnail and then we start make api calls to fetch the video). We Play the video as we stream.

I need to share to all the available applications that have the sharing feature (I can use android implicit intents to do that).

Its like sharing a complete clip and the other user should be able to play in on device player. (If shared to whatsapp, it should open up and play).

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to know about intents to share.  What else are you looking for here-  that is the way you share on Android.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html .... you probably also want to look into deep links. :)

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I didnot implement the VideoPlayer logic and im confused how to share the video (we just pass the stream to VideoPlayer how will I get the complete video for sharing). Im not clear on how to pass the streamed video (we are not saving the video locally we just make a call and attach it to Video player).

Comment: Take the url you stream from and share that.

Comment: Its a Https service, would it automatically fetch the video and send it as a Video instead of a url ?